# Streaming from VLC to chromecast via Stream/Destination

Tags: vlc-media-player, chromecast

I'm looking to stream a movie with subtitles to Chromecast using VLC. I know my Chromecast's IP; I would like to use *Convert * Stream* functionality, what are the right options to configure in the panel below, with respect to:

- `Type`
- `TTL`
- `Port`
- Any announcement configuration I should set up?

[image: VLC Options]

Comment: Might help https://www.techrora.com/how-to/vlc-chromecast-subtitles

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I've seen that article; it doesn't answer the question concerning the specific configuration. I think screenshots are from older VLC version.